# Create a related content block by date and taxonomy?

Tags: blocks, views, datetime

I have two content types, A and B. Both of the content types are tagged with terms from Taxonomy list C.

Content A and B both have a date field (start and end date).

When looking at Content A I want to see all the related content, in a block, with similar Taxonomy (from list C) and also filter by date so that if there are any overlaps it shows i.e.

End Date A > Start Date B > Start Date A or End Date A > End Date B > Start Date A

I have been able to do the first part with contextual filters, but not the second part - can anyone help please? (I am a bit of a novice so may need specifics :))

Thanks!